# Admin Tools, could already visited items be hidden when revisiting?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

I review / audit a question / answer like this:

[MYSQL insert to db utf-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410595/mysql-insert-to-db-utf-8-string/22410938#22410938)

And it comes back everytime I start a review session / audit. Stack Overflow has so many smart algorithms, it is not possible to show a task only once, *if* you respond and actively do something by that task? Like opening it? I can't downvote / upvote more than once, or dismiss more than once etc. If I have opened it once and not made a decision, it is because I do not have the knowledge to become a judge over that question, or answer. Like a special question about `C#`, I cannot judge, always, if it is a really bad answer or just a short and very precise answer.

A feature request for the "Admin Tools" could be to show not-visited items only.

Another solution could be presenting people for audits by the scope of tags they have. I have good reps on [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) but none in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) - try sort the audits by relevance according to the user.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "admin tools". Do you mean 10k tools?

Comment: @Doorknob, Yes - the blue icon on the header, letting you audit flagged items much easier

Comment: That's 10k tools. If the answer looks like it could be an answer to the question, mark the flags as invalid. You shouldn't have to have knowledge of the topic to handle a flag - NAA flags are for stuff like "I have the same problem" or "thanks this helped".

Comment: @Doorknob, Yes, but that is not the issue here. The issue is, that I see that question next time I audit also. And that is not nessecary.

Comment: Really? After I flag a post there, it never appears again.

Comment: Yes, `after you post a flag`, not after you just have visited the question and realized you are unable to jugde! Mark as false flag is a jugde also!

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. So you're asking for a "remove from queue" button, basically? Like the "skip" button in the review queues. I agree, then; that would be useful! +1

Comment: @Doorknob, exactly that. And also the audits not come back if I allready have made some kind of action, like opened them but not jugded.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, there is no accepted answer in your link, and the question is not completely the same. I was careful before posting this.

Comment: Both ask to skip items in the 10k tools so similar enough in my opinion. Not having answer is not relevant, if something was asked already there's no point to ask for it again, there are proper ways to bump. (Editing, bounty)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, you are wrong, SO / MSO is about answers you can trust an learn about. It is not about links to questions who have asked the same before without getting an answer.

Comment: No, I'm not wrong and feel free to start a discussion about it. (e.g. "Should feature request be closed as duplicate of similar request that has no answer yet")

Comment: Feature request need no answers, it would be shame to loose them but they could survive without answers at all. Did you honestly post this to get an answer or to have the feature actually implemented. Almost all answers on feature requests are actually arguments as to why a feature *shouldn't* be implemented and the rest are usually a sign that the original question did a bad job explaining the position: you don't really want answers, you want a [status-completed] tag

Comment: I wrote this [Q&A to answer the question of why feature requests don't need answers to be duplicate targets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225852/220332)

Comment: Hi @RichardTingle, the whole misere is caused by I didnt knew the "official" term is "10k tools". So when I looked for similar answers there was no hit, I looked for "admin tools" as they are named in the documentation. It is propably also why people in the beginning was confused about what I really target. When you have confirmed reading this message I delete the question. Regards ...

Comment: @davidkonrad Duplicates are useful! Personally I wouldn't delete. I'll even give you a +1 to sweeten the deal